# How to save instrumented java bytecode by Java Agent?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

[Java Agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) provides services needed to instrument Java programming language code. [ClassFileTransformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.security.ProtectionDomain-byte:A-) is an implementation for Java Agent, and the transformation occurs before the class is defined by the JVM. The only method `transform` is required to implement, and it is called for every new class definition. An illustration of how `Java Agent` works:

[image: Java Agent]

**I want to save the instrumented code**, so that I can run the instrumented class file without instrumenting every time. As I checked [Interface Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html), I didn't see any direct api to save the transformed bytecode. I wonder whether it is possible to use `Java Agent` to achieve my goal, or some other tools?

Comment: Are you instrumenting your own classes or a 3rd-party library?

Comment: @vempo my own classes, sample codes with source code available.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is build-time or compile-time instrumentation, not run-time. Most bytecode instrumentation tools support both - [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/), [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/), [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/developer-guide.html).

Actually, you could save the bytecode instrumented by your agent to a `.class` file the result of it is just a byte array that represents a class. However, you will have to run your program at least once with the agent, and make sure you load all classes you want to instrument so that a `.class` file is created for each. So **I don't recommend this method**.

```
if (shouldInstrument) {

    CtClass cclass = pool.get(className.replaceAll("/", "."));

    // Instrument the class here

    byte[] bytecode = cclass.toBytecode();

    File outputFile = new File(String.format("%s/%s.class", outputDirectory, className));
    Files.createDirectories(outputFile.getParentFile().toPath());

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        fos.write(bytecode);
    }

    return bytecode;
}
```

Also, if your goal is to add some functionality to your own classes without polluting the source code with a boilerplate code, you can manipulate the source code instead of the bytecode. Source -> generated source -> bytecode (compile). For example, using annotations and a custom [annotation processor](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101).

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned save the bytecode instrumented by your agent to a `.class` file. I tried that, but I found that the `transform` function was called for every class. I also tried to save all the tranformed code to one class, but it is not working.

Comment: I meant the you could instrument only classes you need and save them in respective class files.

Comment: What do you mean by "outmost class"? Are you talking about inner classes? I think you are working with incorrect assumptions here. All classes declared in a single Java source file still have each its own .class file. The transform() method is applied not to a Java source file, but to each individual class - classes are loaded one at a time. Try running my code and for inner classes you will see something like Test$1.class (anonymous), Test$Inner.class, Test$Inner$Deeper.class etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I misunderstood that java can be compiled to a single class file.